# How to run vimtutor in Neovim

Tags: neovim

Is it possible to run `vimtutor` in Neovim?

I'm learning Vim, but I installed Neovim and would like to run `vimtutor` in Neovim.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are learning Neovim, not Vim.

Comment: @romainl Yeah but the Vim commands work in Neovim, too.

Comment: No, not all of them. Look, you made a choice. The two programs are not interchangeable so it's either one *or* the other. When learning, when looking for plugins, and when asking for help.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was under impression Neovim is Vim with plugins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run the 30-minute tutorial on Neovim : `:Tutor<Enter>`

See Neovim intro documentation : https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html